# sqlsrv update where not all passed vars have data

Tags: insert-update, sqlsrv

I am making a form for employees to update their demographics, address, phone, email, etc. The information is placed in a processing table that is then processed to on file on Mondays. I didn't want to place multiple lines in the processing table for one person, so the scenario that someone comes in on Tuesday with a new address and then comes back on Thursday with a new phone, gets updated on the same line.
I've done this:

```
UPDATE PendingProcessing 
SET Street1 = ISNULL(NULLIF('{$addr1}',''), Street1), 
    Street2 = ISNULL(NULLIF('{$addr2}',''), Street2), 
    Email = IsNull(NULLIF('{$email}',''), Email), 
    CellPhone = IsNull(NULLIF('{$cellPhone}',''), CellPhone), 
    HomePhone = IsNull(NULLIF('{$homePhone}',''),HomePhone), 
    City = IsNull(NULLIF('{$city}',''), City), 
    State = IsNull(NULLIF('{$state}',''),State), 
    Zip = IsNull(NULLIF('{$zip}',''),Zip), 
    DateOfChangeRequest = '{$date}' 
WHERE  Clock = '{$username}';  

IF (@@ROWCOUNT = 0) 
BEGIN 
    IF (NOT EXISTS( SELECT * FROM PendingProcessing WHERE  Clock = '{$username}' ))
    BEGIN 
        INSERT INTO PendingProcessing 
        (
            Clock, 
            Street1, 
            Street2,  
            Email, 
            CellPhone, 
            HomePhone, 
            City, 
            State, 
            Zip, 
            DateOfChangeRequest
        ) 
        VALUES 
        (
            '{$username}', 
            '{$addr1}',
            '{$addr2}',
            '{$email}',
            '{$cellPhone}',
            '{$homePhone}',
            '{$city}',
            '{$state}',
            '{$zip}',
            '{$date}'
        ); 
    END; 
END;
```

But the problem is that if there is an address in the Street1 column when a phone number comes in it only leaves the first character in Street1.

The short way is to make the user enter their new address again when entering their new phone number because the first address update was still pending processing. I would prefer to make the code do the extra work though.

So, my question is how can I update columns only when I have data to update them with? I don't want to null existing data, but I also don't want to not update something that has data, say the user entered their new phone number and realized after saving that they had made a typo and needed to change that number.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Isn't `ISNULL` itself sufficient? If the new incoming value is null, take the previous value from table: `Street1 = ISNULL('{$addr1}', Street1)`.By the way, if `@@ROWCOUNT` equals 0, there is no record for `Clock = '{$username}'` and therefore you don't need `NOT EXISTS` query.

Comment: I've tried it both as "Street1 = ISNULL('{$addr1}', Street1)" and as in my post, both will leave the existing contents first character, not the full content for whatever reason.

Comment: My previous reply is wrong.  "Street1 = ISNULL('{$addr1}', Street1)"  Will null the existing, while "Street1 = ISNULL(NULLIF('{$addr1}',''), Street1)" leaves the first character of the existing. I did test them both yesterday, but forgot there was a difference.

Comment: `ISNULL` never returns `NULL`. Try logging query before execution. Moreover, I suggest you to use parameterized queries: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/how-to-perform-parameterized-queries . By using this, your code will be more secure (by avoiding SQL injection) and you do less mistakes IMO.

Comment: Thanks @alalp, I'll take a look and see what I can get working. I was going to use this on my vars before they are ever passed to my php though: `code` function anti_injection_login($sql, $formUse = true)
{
$sql = preg_replace("/(from|select|insert|delete|where|drop table|show tables|,|'|#|\*|--|\\\\)/i","",$sql);
$sql = trim($sql);
$sql = strip_tags($sql);
if(!$formUse || !get_magic_quotes_gpc())
  $sql = addslashes($sql);
return $sql;
} `code` Its not in use yet, wanted to get it working without it first

Comment: Could you not create a dynamic query in PHP... So, having the form values in an associative array with the key being the column name. Then run a `foreach`, check the values using `empty` or `is_null` and append non-null key-values to a `SET` string used in the query.

Comment: I like the dynamic query idea and will use it someplace else. What I ended up doing for this is if the user has a pending update, I hide the save button and give them a view pending button that loads the form with all pending data and displays the save button again. That way if they change something it all gets updated together. This helps for checking if they typo'ed something since they can see it. Thanks for your help.